# Repeat elements of a list

Tags: haskell

I am writing a small function repeat k lt. it will repeat all elements in a list k times.

This is my approach and following is the code i tried

```
repeat 0 xs = xs
repeat k [] = []
repeat k (x:xs)
     |k == 1 = x:repeat 0 xs
     |otherwise = x:repeat (k-1) xs
```

Then i realized i am just removing the head and pushing it back inside. so do i use  `++` operator? I know there are other ways of solving this problem but i want to learn how to do it recursively as it can be done easily by using list comprehensions.

Please advice.

Comment: For clarification, what should `repeat 3 [1,2]` return, e.g. `[1,2,1,2,1,2]` or `[1,1,1,2,2,2]`?

Comment: it should be [1,1,1,2,2,2]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want recursion:

```
repeat 0 xs     = []
repeat n []     = []
repeat n (x:xs) = x : repeat (n - 1) [x] ++ repeat n xs
```

`repeat 3 [1,2,3]` gives

```
1 : repeat 2 [1] ++ repeat 3 [2,3]
1 : 1 : repeat 1 [1] ++ repeat 2 [] ++ repeat 3 [2,3]
1 : 1 : 1 : repeat 0 [1] ++ [] ++ repeat 3 [2,3]
1 : 1 : 1 : 2 : repeat 2 [2] ++ repeat 3 [3]
1 : 1 : 1 : 2 : 2 : repeat 1 [2] ++ repeat 2 [] ++ repeat 3 [3]
1 : 1 : 1 : 2 : 2 : 2 : repeat 0 [2] ++ repeat 3 [3]
1 : 1 : 1 : 2 : 2 : 2 : 3 : repeat 2 [3] ++ repeat 3 []
1 : 1 : 1 : 2 : 2 : 2 : 3 : 3 : repeat 1 [3] ++ repeat 2 [] ++ repeat 3 []
1 : 1 : 1 : 2 : 2 : 2 : 3 : 3 : 3 : []
```

This is ugly and inefficient. Here are nicer solutions:

```
repeat' = concatMap . replicate

repeat'' n xs = [x | x <- xs, _ <- [1..n]]

repeat''' n = concat . transpose . replicate n
```